# error 404 in another folder

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I have a website and I have configured the .htaccess like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

But, when we try to access to a folder html page in the website like this (this page doesn't exists) :

```
http://www.copyrightdepot.com/cd88/0005654.htm
```

This should show this :

```
http://www.copyrightdepot.com/404.php
```

It looks like the page didn't have access to the css and js files... Do I have to create another 404.php in the **cd88** folder?

Comment: if the `.htaccess` is only inside that said folder; yes you will most likely need to create a new one for the other folder. If that is the case, why don't you just put it inside your root instead (IF that's the case here). where is the .htaccess in now?

Comment: the .htaccess is in the root folder... Now, that's working using full URL of the 404 page :)

Answer (score 2):

> The http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument say:
>
> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the > > DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve. Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URL shown in the browser's address bar requires a redirect. `ErrorDocument` by itself does NOT do a redirect.

Think about it: The user's arrived at your site with a non-existent url, causing a 404. They get shown the specified ErrorDocument, and their browser will internally show a 404 status on the request.

If ErrorDocument did a redirect, the browser would show TWO requests.

1. the original "bad" url, receiving a 301/302 redirect
2. a new request for http://example.com/404.php, receiving a 200 OK response.

Telling the user the requested page doesn't exist, while simultaneously serving up that message via a 200 OK is a non-sequitur. "Hi, I'm Fred, but I don't exist".

Standard behavior for a 404 response is to assume it's temporary, and try the URL again. If the browser receives a 301 (permanent) redirect instead, it'll never go back to the original (bad) url, and automatically load the /404.php page instead - even if the original URL is repaired and would serve up content.